# Sort a vector of Template values

Tags: c++

So I have this class.

```
template <class T>
class MyVector {
vector<T> v;
public:
 MyVector();
 ~MyVector();
 T max() const;
 bool hasDuplicates(void) const;
};
```

Let's say I want my function `max` to sort the vector using `std::sort` and then return the last element?
How would I sort this vector ?

Comment: Sounds like you'd better use 'std::max_element'.

Comment: Sorting is one job, finding the max is another. Your function called `max()` should do only one. Also, it's marked as `const`, so you couldn't do the sort in that function anyway.

Comment: It's not what people normally prefer to use C++ for, but you don't need to sort `v`. You can make a local copy of `v` in your function and sort that copy.

Comment: I'm not convinced that paying for the copy *and* the sort is cheaper than a simple linear search. O(n) versus O(nlg n).

Comment: @sweenish it's likely a homework, with `hasDuplicates()` involving sorting too.

Comment: That just makes a stronger case for the sort being it’s own function per my first comment. DRY, after all.

Comment: Dunno what your usecase for this is, but in addition to the other answers, there are a few more options: 1. You could always keep the vector sorted by inserting elements where they should be (the performance of this might degrade on larger vectors compared to sorting), and 2. std::(unordered_)(multi)set may also be an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question raises an interesting point, although somewhat inadvertently. It is true that when you have a sorted array, finding the max is quite easy. Similarly, your function `hasDuplicates()` also becomes simpler when the vector is sorted.

However, both functions are marked as `const`, meaning that they are not allowed to alter the state of the object.

Now because both functions work better on a sorted array, but they cannot do the sort themselves, we'll separate our concerns and add a sort function that we can use. In order to preserve the `const`-ness, we'll change the behavior of the class to that of an always-sorted vector.

Before we start with that, there are two critiques of the code you posted. You added a destructor, but it's not necessary at all. Your private `std::vector` can destroy itself, and your `MyVector` class has no other dynamic resources which would require a written destructor to handle properly. At least with what you've shown.

The second critique is that the formatting of the code is inconsistent. Well-formatted code is easier to read and understand. There are tools like clang-format that can auto-format your code for you.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <class T>
class MySortedVector {
  void sort();  // Should be called at the end of any member function that
                // alters state

  std::vector<T> v;

 public:
  MySortedVector();
  MySortedVector(std::initializer_list<T> list);  // Convenience for the example

  void push_back(T val);  // For demonstration purposes
  T max() const;
  bool hasDuplicates(void) const;

  // Convenience for debugging
  void print() const;
};

template <typename T>
void MySortedVector<T>::sort() {
  std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
}

template <typename T>
MySortedVector<T>::MySortedVector(std::initializer_list<T> list) : v{list} {
  sort();
}

template <typename T>
void MySortedVector<T>::push_back(T val) {
  v.push_back(val);
  sort();
}

template <typename T>
T MySortedVector<T>::max() const {
  return v.back();
}

template <typename T>
bool MySortedVector<T>::hasDuplicates(void) const {
  // TODO: Implement
}

template <typename T>
void MySortedVector<T>::print() const {
  for (const auto& i : v) {
    std::cout << i << ' ';
  }
  std::cout << '\n';
}

int main() {
  MySortedVector<int> one{9, 8, 7, 4, 3, 2, 1};
  one.print();
  std::cout << one.max() << '\n';

  one.push_back(5);
  one.push_back(20);
  one.print();
  std::cout << one.max() << '\n';

  MySortedVector<std::string> two{"How", "Now", "Brown", "Cow"};
  two.print();
  std::cout << two.max() << '\n';
  two.push_back("how");
  two.push_back("cow");
  two.print();
  std::cout << two.max() << '\n';
}
```

The key is that any member function that can alter the state of the private vector must call `sort()` before returning. This preserves your class invariant. I also changed the name of the type to better describe what it now is.

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 7 8 9 
9
1 2 3 4 5 7 8 9 20 
20
Brown Cow How Now 
Now
Brown Cow How Now cow how 
how
```

Now, this does make finding the max trivial, but it's also unnecessary. A simple linear search to identify the max element is going to be faster than fully sorting the vector.

Finding duplicates, on the other hand, is an algorithm where the sorting pays for itself. Exceptions require specific use cases, like specific types and ranges where counting can be faster.